# Expected Length of a Binomial Proportion?

Tags: probability

I was reading this article (https://www.scirp.org/pdf/ojs_2021101415023495.pdf) here and came across the following equations (page 7):

1. Coverage Probability of a Binomial Random Variable:

$$Cp(p,n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} I(k,n)  \binom{n}{k}  p^k  (1-p)^{n-k}$$

2. Expected Length of the Interval:

$$EL(p,n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}  \binom{n}{k}  p^k  (1-p)^{n-k}  [ U(x) - L(x)]$$

**I am interested in learning how I can derive these two formulas.**

For instance, suppose if I start with some Random Variable "x" that has a Binomial Probability Distribution Function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). I understand that :

- The "Coverage Probability" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverage_probability) refers to probability of the Confidence Interval containing the parameter of interest
- And the "Expected Length" (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18379/expectation-of-length-of-a-confidence-interval, [Estimate length of confidence interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663600/estimate-length-of-confidence-interval)) refers to the length of the Confidence Interval relative to the Variance

**But how can I use this probability distribution function to derive these two formulas starting from the Binomial Probability Distribution Function?**

Thanks!

Comment: Apply the [Law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician): $\mathbb{E}f(X) = \sum_{k=0}^n f(k)\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, when $X\sim\text{Binom}(n,p)$.

Comment: @ user51547 : thank you so much for your suggestion!

Comment: Your $EL$ is missing ${n \choose k}$ from the original article while I am not particularly happy with $U(x)-L(x)$ as I would have thought they should be $U(k,n)-L(k,n)$

Comment: @ Henry: thank you for pointing this out! I now made this correction!